# Update User Agent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, http-headers, user-agent

I would like to change my User Agent while browsing and display the changes on a website.
I already got a website that prints the UserAgent, simply using JS `document.writeln(navigator.userAgent)`.

When I load this page with Chrome, it displays my default UA (let's say `abc`). When I change it to `xyz` and refresh (Ctrl+F5), it displays the new UA `xyz`.
Great, that is exactly what I wanted!

Now if I do the same thing with Firefox, the displayed UA won't update.
So I load the page with `abc` as my UA, I change it to `xyz`, refresh the site (again without cache) but it still displays `abc`.

The Apache logs and Wireshark both show that the UA transported in the HTTP header is actually the new `xyz`.

Does anyone of you have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: I'd really love to understand *why* you're trying to do this, because while it's an interesting question, I can't imagine any good reason for wanting to do this programmatically from within a web page.

Comment: You're most likely modifying the Request header sent by Firefox while your JS reads the `navigator` object.

Comment: There is no particular (useful) reason for this! I'm a teaching assistant for a MOOC about Internet technologies, and I'm preparing a task on HTTP headers. The students are supposed to fiddle with them in order to get a more practical understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of you suggested I had read the navigator object, not the actual HTTP header, thanks for that!

I solved it using PHP instead:

```
    <?php
        $header=getallheaders();
        foreach ($header as $name => $value) 
        {
            echo "$name: $value<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```

Or just

```
    <?php
        $header=getallheaders();
        $ua=$header["User-Agent"];
        echo "$ua<br/>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent):

> In Firefox, you can change the preference general.useragent.override in about:config. Some Firefox extensions do that; however, this only changes the HTTP header that gets sent, and doesn't affect browser detection performed by JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, sounds reasonable.
So is there a way to read the actual UA sent in the HTTP header in a website?